# quarkus - how to specify Hosting options and plan for azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, quarkus

While using `./mvnw quarkus:deploy`

The default  ***Hosting options and plan*** of Quarkus azure function is *App Service Plan*
How to set ***Hosting options and plan*** as *Consumption (Serverless)* ?

Not able to find the corresponding config in allconfig on quarkus
[All config](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to deploy Quarkus Azure function to Azure function App with Consumption Plan.
Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java?source=recommendations&tabs=windows,bash,azure-cli,browser#deploy-the-function-project-to-azure).

Deploy the function to Azure function App with Consumption Plan using the command `mvn azure-functions:deploy`.

- I have created a Quarkus Azure function and able to deploy to Consumption Plan.

**Pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-azure-functionn</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.6.4</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-azure-functions</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.30</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>12.25.2</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
       <plugin>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.31.0</version>
      <configuration>
      <appName>quark-azure-function</appName>
      <appServicePlanName></appServicePlanName>
      <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
      <resourceGroup>quarkus</resourceGroup>
    <runtime>
      <os>linux</os>
      <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
    </runtime>
    <appSettings>
      <property>
        <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
         <value>~4</value>
      </property>
    </appSettings>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

- If you don't mention anything in the App Service Plan in the POM.XML configuration, it considers consumption plan during deployment. Refer [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-pricing-tiers) article.

**Console Response:**

```
C:\Users\uname\quarkus-azure-functions\quarkus-azure-functions>mvn azure-functions:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.acme:quarkus-azure-functionn >------------------
[INFO] Building quarkus-azure-functionn 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-functions:1.31.0:deploy (default-cli) @ quarkus-azure-functionn ---
[INFO] Auth type: AZURE_CLI
[INFO] Username: uname@XXX.com
[INFO] Subscription: <subscription_name>
[INFO] Start creating Storage Account(3a67ac0cf7cf4bd98240)...
[INFO] Storage Account(3a67ac0cf7cf4bd98240) is successfully created.
[INFO] Start creating Application Insights (quark-azure-function)...
[INFO] Application Insights (quark-azure-function) is successfully created.
[INFO] Start creating App Service plan (asp-quark-azure-function)...
[INFO] App Service plan (asp-quark-azure-function) is successfully created
[INFO] Set function worker runtime to java.
[INFO] Start creating Function App(quark-azure-function)...
[INFO] Function App(quark-azure-function) is successfully created
[INFO] Starting deployment...
[INFO] Trying to deploy artifact to quark-azure-function...
[INFO] Successfully deployed the artifact to https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net
[INFO] Deployment succeed
[INFO] Syncing triggers and fetching function information
[INFO] Querying triggers...
[INFO] HTTP Trigger Urls:
         CreateNote : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/notes
         DeleteAllNotes : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/notes
         DeleteNote : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/notes/{id}
         GetAllBlobs : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/blobs
         GetAllNotes : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/notes
         GetInvoiceSampleForMonth : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/invoice
         GetNoteById : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/notes/{id}
         UpdateNote : https://quark-azure-function.azurewebsites.net/api/notes/{id}

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-08T20:23:18+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Portal:**

[image]